# Images in NSImageViews randomly turned upside-down

Tags: cocoa, rotation, nsimageview

So, I have this odd issue in my Cocoa app. A toolbar item, and some NSImageViews just render their image upside-down for no apparent reason. The toolbar item actually comes that way when I launch the App for some reason (the icon is assigned in code), and then, when I open my HUD with a finder zoom effect, the imageViews contained in it are upside down.

[image]

That image above is a screensot of this odd phenomenon. AS you can see, the "Show Trash" item is rotated oddly, every NSImageView in the HUD, but the NSImageView in the NSBrowser is fine.

How would I go about tracking down what is causing this, and then fixing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Mac OS X Developer Release Note - AppKit Release Notes (Snow Leopard)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_6Notes):

> **Flipped images in toolbars (New since
>   January 2009 seed)**
>
> A common but incorrect practice is to
>   call `setFlipped:YES` on an image that
>   you plan to draw into a flipped
>   graphics context. This is incorrect
>   because if the image is later drawn
>   into a normal unflipped context, the
>   image will appear upside down.
>   However, Leopard and earlier contained
>   a bug in which images set on
>   `NSToolbarItem` (via `setImage:`) would
>   ignore their `isFlipped` property.
>   SnowLeopard fixes this bug for apps
>   compiled on SnowLeopard with the 10.6
>   SDK; as a result, some images which
>   should have drawn upside down in
>   Leopard, will begin doing so when your
>   app is recompiled.
>
> If you recompile your app on
>   SnowLeopard and discover that your
>   toolbar item images are drawing upside
>   down, then it indicates that you are
>   calling `setFlipped:YES` somewhere
>   within your code. You should remove
>   those calls and replace the image
>   drawing with methods that correctly
>   handle flipped contexts. See the
>   discussion of `setFlipped:` in these
>   Release Notes for more discussion.

Re: `setFlipped:`

> **NSImage: deprecating -[NSImage
>   setFlipped:], adding a drawing method
>   that respects context flippedness (New
>   since WWDC 2008)**
>
> The flipped attribute of `NSImage` is
>   widely misunderstood.  We are
>   deprecating it for SnowLeopard, and
>   replacing its typical uses with less
>   error-prone API.
>
> The property describes the orientation
>   of the internal coordinate system of
>   the `NSImage`.  Just as a superview
>   never cares about the flippedness of
>   its subviews, a user of an `NSImage`
>   should not care about its flippedness.
>
> The typical (flawed) use case is to
>   try to call `[image
>   setFlipped:[[NSGraphicsContext
>   currentContext] isFlipped]]` just prior
>   to drawing, but this does not
>   accomplish the intended goal.  If
>   called before caching, then
>   representations end up caching upside
>   down, and the flip is absorbed into
>   the cache.  If called after caching,
>   it has no effect-the cached
>   representation is already supposed to
>   incorporate any necessary flipping. 
>   In the former case, if the `NSImage` is
>   drawn anywhere else later, it ends up
>   upside down in *that* place, which is
>   also confusing because the bug and the
>   expression of the bug are far apart. 
>   Lack of understanding regarding
>   flippedness is also frequently the
>   source of poorly performing code, in
>   which people make unnecessary
>   intermediate buffers to work around
>   perceived framework bugs.  The
>   framework behaves according to design,
>   but contrary to expectation, and the
>   semantics are not all that useful.
>   It's also difficult to change the
>   semantics of `-[NSImage isFlipped]`,
>   because a lot of code is very closely
>   dependent on the current behavior.
>   Rather than attempt this, we have
>   deprecated the property.
>
> We are providing a simple and correct
>   way to draw images in a flipped or
>   unflipped context, which is a draw
>   method that can account for context
>   flippedness.  We are also adding a
>   hints parameter matching the hints in `-bestRepresentationForRect:context:hints:`.
>
> `- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)dstRect
>             fromRect:(NSRect)srcRect
>            operation:(NSCompositingOperation)op
>             fraction:(CGFloat)alpha
>       respectFlipped:(BOOL)respectContextIsFlipped
>                hints:(NSDictionary *)hints;`
>
> Pass `YES` for `respectFlipped` to get the fancy new behavior. One
>   note for those that understand the CTM
>   and worry that this method has an odd
>   interaction, where modifying the CTM
>   could fail to have any effect on image
>   drawing: This is not the case. This
>   method branches behavior based on
>   `[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
>   isFlipped]`. Modifying the CTM might
>   turn your axes upside down, but it
>   will not alter the result of
>   `-[NSGraphicsContext isFlipped]`. They're completely orthogonal.
>
> A second valid use of `-[NSImage
>   setFlipped:]` was to specify the
>   flippedness of the context obtained
>   via `-[NSImage lockFocus]`.  There are
>   cases, for example drawing directly
>   via `NSLayoutManager`, that require a
>   flipped context.  To cover this case,
>   we add
>
> `- (void)lockFocusFlipped:(BOOL)flipped;`
>
> This doesn't alter the state of the
>   image itself, only the context on
>   which focus is locked. It means that
>   (0,0) is at the top left and positive
>   along the Y-axis is down in the locked
>   context.

Comment: "We are providing a simple and correct way to draw images."

I am using a "filmstrip" type animation of a knob. The problem with NSImage is it silently "flips" the image when loading/caching. Without "respectFlipped" (in a flipped view) the images render upside-down. However *with* "respectFlipped" my frames draw the correct way up, but they animate in the *opposite* order they are supposed to. i.e. the first frame is now last.
  This is very weird, and not intuitive. using -[NSImage isFlipped] fixes the problem neatly though. I don't think it should be deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

My off-the-top-of-my-head guess is that the image has mistakenly had `-setFlipped:YES` called on it.

Comment: Nowhere in my code was setFlipped used, so this must be some sort of strange bug, but explicitly setting the Images to not be flipped did the trick. What could possibly cause something that? Also, I only noticed this happening in the NIB I stored this specific group of windows in. The main window, which was in another NIB, were unaffected by this.

Comment: You could set a symbolic breakpoint on -[NSImage setFlipped:] and see when it's changing.